# Slow loading of js scripts in spring boot 3 environment with thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, performance

In my spring boot application (spring boot version 3.1.4 currentlty), Scripts written in react load slowly - usually a minute per script. This slow loading prevents my users from authenticating.

I haven't found the reason for this problem, nor any section on this site that talks about this problem.

I upgrade recently the version spring boot (version 3.1.4) and java (17). In the previous version for this components - spring boot 2 and java 11, the application works correctly.

The script is called by in the index.html by the command window.**basename** = .

The problem occurs from the jar, when the program is run under an editor like idea intellij, the problem does not reproduce.

Do you have an idea to resolve the problem?